# hightchart tickinterval between two xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the code to display two data on line chart :

```
    $(function () {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'spline'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Snow depth atasfsa Vikjafjellet, Norway'
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                  tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,

              day: '%a'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Date'
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Snow depth (m)'
          },
          min: 0
      },
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
      },

      plotOptions: {
          pointInterval: 10,
          spline: {
              marker: {
                  enabled: true
              }
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'A',
          // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
          // of 2016/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
          // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
          data: [
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 1), 0],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 2), 0.28],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 3), 0.25],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 4), 0.2],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 5), 0.28],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 6), 0.28],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 7), 0.47],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 8), 0.47],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 9), 0.47],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 10), 0.47],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 11), 0.47],
              [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 12), 0.47]
          ]
      }, {
          name: 'B',
                    data: [
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1), 0],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2), 0.4],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 3), 0.25],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 4), 1.66],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 5), 1.8],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 6), 1.76],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 7), 2.62],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 8), 2.41],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 9), 2.05],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 10), 1.7],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 11), 1.1],
          [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 12), 0]
      ]
      }]
  });
});
```

output: [image]

i wonder how to make B xAxis start from 'sun' at A xAxis ?
i have been googling but a can't found anything and I do not know what to look for....

Comment: Can you explain more what you expect? Do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5wd10o2k/

Comment: yes @morganfree, but with `opposite: false`. basically a want to make each data begins from the first day of each month so, A xaxis begins from thursday and when Sunday comes then B Xaxis begins. is there any other function that i can use?

Comment: So, I can't help but ask why, here? If you just plot the data normally on a single axis, won't that do exactly what you're asking for, by default?